# toLocaleDateString Javascript date format issues

Tags: javascript, string, date, datetime, cross-browser

I've got a script and i want to format a date out to short date format ie:

7/3/2013 or 7/3/13 the first date format renders like that in Chrome but every other browser it does not - it displays the date month name and the year.

```
function dateFormatter(date) {
  return date.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

Bit confused as to why this is happening. Is it because that browser doesnt support tolocalDateString();

Would i need to build a custom date string in order for it to work?

Sorry if its a little vague - I've had a look on W3C website but dont trust that site at times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function dateFormatter(date){
    if(Date.parse('2/6/2009')=== 1233896400000){
        return [date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate(), date.getFullYear()].join('/');
    }
    return [date.getDate(), date.getMonth()+1, date.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

Comment: This is not locale-aware at all...

Comment: @kennebec that worked perfectly. I tried something similar to this but to be honest i just messed it up. But yes that worked smoothly. Cheers.

Comment: @kennebec, what is with the if condition doing, why do we need this weird 2/6/2009 date check?

Comment: It's a locale thing... some places the month is first, and in others it is second... so this actually is totally locale-aware

Comment: @SerjSagan: This answer is not locale-aware in three respects: (a) the behavior of `Date.parse()` with strings other than in the [ISO 8601-based format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) is [implementation-defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse).
(b) the output uses fixed separator `/`, and (c) locales whose short date format places the _year_ first are not taken into account.

Answer (score 10):

The default format of `toLocaleDateString` is implementation-defined. If you want precise control of what's displayed, use a browser supporting [`locales` and `options` arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility) to `toLocaleDateString`. Unfortunately, at the moment that means only Chrome.

If you don't care about the user and their locale and would like to confuse everyone with US date format, then yes, you can hardcode the date parts as @kennebec suggested.